¿Por que no se marca el Seleccionar todos al inicio? Se marca pero se desmarca
tengo un componente que renderiza checkbox para establecer filtros sobre un estado recibido del padre. los checkbox se renderizan en base al data subtypes.
No consigo hacer que en la renderizacion inicial se queden marcados todos los checkboses
export const LeftBaseSection = ({ subtypes, setSelectedSubtypes }) => {
    const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState(subtypes.map(subtype => subtype.code));

    const handleCheckboxClick = (code) => {
        setSelectedItems(prevItems => {
            if (prevItems.includes(code)) {
                return prevItems.filter(item => item !== code);
            } else {
                return [...prevItems, code];
            }
        });
    };

    const handleSelectAllClick = () => {
        setSelectedItems(prevItems => {
            if (prevItems.length === subtypes.length) {
                return [];
            } else {
                return subtypes.map(subtype => subtype.code);
            }
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const selectedCodes = new Set(selectedItems);
        const filteredSubtypes = subtypes.filter(subtype => selectedCodes.has(subtype.code));
        setSelectedSubtypes(filteredSubtypes);
    }, [selectedItems]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="selectAll"
                    name="selectAll"
                    value="selectAll"
                    onChange={handleSelectAllClick}
                    checked={selectedItems.length === subtypes.length}
                />
                <label htmlFor="selectAll">Seleccionar todo</label>
            </div>
            {subtypes.map((subtype) => (
                <div key={subtype.id}>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        id={subtype.code}
                        name={subtype.code}
                        value={subtype.code}
                        onChange={() => handleCheckboxClick(subtype.code)}
                        checked={selectedItems.includes(subtype.code)}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor={subtype.code}>{subtype.code}</label>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

